# How does Arduino Wiring Language work?

Tags: arduino

I am new to Arduino and just read from the book < *Intel Galileo and Intel Galileo Gen 2 API Features and Arduino Projects for Linux Programmers* > that:

> In 2003, a student named Hernando Barragan created a hardware thesis
>   describing an IDE and the integration with circuit boards powered by
>   micro-controllers. With contributions from other researches the concept
>   evolved ***allowing developers to write just a few lines of code in order***
>   ***to reproduce simple connections of hardware components.***

Could anyone explain ***how software could change hardware wiring*** as the bold part says?

Comment: You might have used basic functions like ```pinMode()/digitalRead()/digitalWrite()```/etc. Let's take the example of an LED being turned on as a button is pressed. By writing code, you're wiring hardware elements like the physical switch and the LED, reading from one and writing to the other. Does this help mentally create image of a 'wire' created by programming ? The fun part is having your code do more than a wire (e.g. you can blink/fade/animate the LED, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not talking about changing physical wires. It means the code can drive a micro-controller to communicate with the hardware. Each pin of a micro-controller can do different things and speak with different hardware but you do have to physically connect the hardware yourself.

For example:-

To communicate with different hardware, such as a gps, we plug the gps wires into pins of the micro-controller and then use code to monitor the pins. The Arduino will monitor the voltage on the pins to determine power on/off (0's and 1's) and allow you to know the result in your own code. It is similar to morse code but much faster. Eight zero's or 1's gives us one byte, one byte is one letter or number. Wait long enough and we have a whole message (in reality it takes a few milliseconds for quite a big message)

Some hardware uses 0's and 1's as described above, some uses analog values to give readings. For example a temperature sensor, when powered, might produce a voltage between 0 and 5 volts. It would have a wire that plugs into one of the Analog pins on the Arduino. The Arduino code can read the voltage of the temperature sensor connected to an analog pin, perform a bunch of calculations and determine what the temperature is.

Some hardware such as motors and other sensors use more complex `messaging systems` but all connect to pins of the Arduino micro-controller to be read or written to using the methods described in the specification of the hardware. Normally this involves some quite complex code but Arduino/Wiring is a simple set of instructions that in the background uses the complex code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's really helpful. It's totally understandable. It cleared much confusion I had before.

Comment: I may have some more questions related to this thread. I will ponder first and post them later.